# problems with the internet connection in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS!

Tags: networking, updates

I come from ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I never have problems of any kind, but since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I've had a real hell: I can navigate perfectly through Mozilla but when using apt commands I just get an error.

I read somewhere there were problems with the ipv6, after deactivated followed the same problem.

I do not know what else to do, I also realized that the problem affects the terminal updates, simply the pc is isolated less by browsers, try to migrate to the last version of Elememtary OS and the same thing happened to me.

I do not know anything about this and I'm probably the newest user around here but I suspect that it has to do with the last kernel! I dont know!!!!

The error message (translated in english) is:
`The connection to cu.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001: 67c: 1560: 8001 :: 14) can not be started. - connect (101: The network is inaccessible)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other mirror/repository?

Comment: I tried everything, but nothing, now apt connects sporadically, and has never connected for example the app center, the system detected a group of updates that weighed 180Mb and could never download them because it failed, now it is not even connected to the internal servers that we have in Cuba, which by the way are updated day by day, none of this happened to me with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Greetings and thanks for replying!

Comment: leave another screenshot for more detail